# Adding an IF statement to not print a link if its URL is an empty string

Tags: php

I have the following code from the developer of my Wordpress site and if possible I'd like to make a revision myself.

```
$list .= '<div class="fc_right">
    <h3>'.$headline.'</h3>
    <div class="fc_caption">'.$caption.'</div>
    <a href="'.$url.'">More &#187;</a>
  </div><div class="clear"></div>
</li>';
```

I just want to add an if statement in there that if $url is blank, then don't print the More>> link.

Let me know if I need to provide more context of the code, I wanted to keep it brief for you all if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$list .= '<div class="fc_right">
    <h3>'.$headline.'</h3>
    <div class="fc_caption">'.$caption.'</div>' .
    ($url == '' ? '' : '<a href="'.$url.'">More &#187;</a>') .
  '</div><div class="clear"></div>
</li>';
```

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing stopping you from adding that `if` statement yourself...

```
$list .= '<div class="fc_right">
    <h3>'.$headline.'</h3>
    <div class="fc_caption">'.$caption.'</div>';

if($url) $list .= '<a href="'.$url.'">More &#187;</a>';

$list .= '</div><div class="clear"></div>
</li>';
```

Comment: What's the point in splitting the `$list` into two different statements?

Comment: @Jared Farrish: It's easier to maintain than a concatenation ternary, especially for someone who's asking if he can add an `if` statement (I personally would of written it in a ternary, but, considering the question's nature....).

Comment: Have you seen my answer? A ternary is not the only option.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Assign a third variable just for that? I'm sorry, but you are better of with a ternary or an `if`. You don't need to allocate memory for this.

Comment: *sigh* I don't think I can get an upvote on that answer to save my life... ;o

Comment: Seriously, I had a ternary before all of the others, but I have had no upvotes, I simply added an alternative to demonstrate it could be done differently. But all of the upvotes went to those with more points than me, even if the answer wasn't even right. c'est la vie.

Answer (score 1):

```
$list .= '<div class="fc_right">
    <h3>'.$headline.'</h3>
    <div class="fc_caption">'.$caption.'</div>' .
    ($url ? '<a href="'.$url.'">More &#187;</a>' : '')
   . '</div><div class="clear"></div>
</li>';
```

Comment: You're missing the `.` concatenation on the ternary. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could either do a string interpolation, or use a ternary:

```
$list .= '<div class="fc_right">
    <h3>'.$headline.'</h3>
    <div class="fc_caption">'.$caption.'</div>
    '.($url != ''?'<a href="'.$url.'">More &#187;</a>':'').'
  </div><div class="clear"></div>
</li>';
```

http://codepad.org/Vt6QbLwY

And in longform:

```
<?php

$url = '';

if ($url == '') {
    $s_url = '';
} else {
    $s_url = '<a href="'.$url.'">More &#187;</a>';
}

$list .= '<div class="fc_right">
    <h3>'.$headline.'</h3>
    <div class="fc_caption">'.$caption.'</div>
    '.$s_url.'
  </div><div class="clear"></div>
</li>';

echo $list;

?>
```

http://codepad.org/a9UisF9i

Answer (score 0):

```
$list .= '<div class="fc_right">
    <h3>'.$headline.'</h3>
    <div class="fc_caption">'.$caption.'</div>';

$list.= if(!empty($url)) ? ' <a href="'.$url.'">More &#187;</a>' : '';

$list.= '</div><div class="clear"></div>
</li>';
```